# Deploying Perl Application

Tags: perl, deployment, psgi

What are the best practices for deploying a Perl application? Assume that you are deploying onto a vanilla box with little CPAN module installation. What are the ideal build, deploy methods? Module::Build, ExtUtils::MakeMaker, other? I am looking for some best practice ideas from those who have done this repeatedly for large scale applications.

The application is deploying onto a server. It's not CPAN or a script. It's actually a PSGI web application. That is, a ton of Perl packages.

I currently have a deployment script that uses Net::SSH::Expect to SSH into new servers, install some tools and configure the server, then pull down the desired application branch from source control. This feels right, but is this best practice?

The next step is building the application. What are the best practices for tracking and managing dependencies, installing those dependencies from CPAN, and ensuring the application is ready to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The company that I work at currently build RPMs for each and every CPAN & Internal dependency of an application (quite a lot of packages!) that install into the system site_perl directory. This has a number of problems:

- It is time consuming to keep building RPMs as versions get bumped across the CPAN.
- Tying yourself to the system perl means that you are at the mercy of your distribution to make or break your perl ( in Centos 5 we have a max perl version of 5.8.8 ! ).
- If you have multiple applications deployed to the same host, having a single perl library for all applications means that upgrading dependencies can be dangerous without retesting every application of the host. We deploy quite a lot of separate distributions all with varying degrees of maintenance attention, so this is a big deal for us.

We are moving away from building RPMs for every dependency and instead planning to use carton [1] to build a completely self contained perl library for every application we deploy. We're building these libraries into system packages, but you could just as easily tarball them up and manually copy them places if you don't want to deal with a package manager.

The problem with carton is that you'll need to setup an internal CPAN mirror that you can install your internal dependencies to if your application depends on modules that aren't on the CPAN. If you don't want to deal with that, you could always just manually install libs you need into local::lib [2] or perlbrew [3] and package the resulting libraries up for deployment to your production boxes.

With all of the prescribed solutions, be very careful of XS perl libs. You'll need to build your cartons/local:libs/perlbrews on the same architecture as the host you're deploying to and make sure your productions boxes have the same binary dependencies as what you used to build.

**To answer the update to your question about whether it is best practice to source checkout and install onto you production host**; I personally don't think that it is a good idea. The reasons why I believe that it is risky lays in the fact that it is hard to be completely sure that the set of libraries that you install exactly lines up to the libraries that you tested against, so deployments have the potential to be unpredictable. This issue can be exasperated by webapps as you are very likely to have the same code deployed to multiple production boxes that can get out of synch, also. While the perl community does a wonderful job of trying to release good quality code that is backwards compatible, when things go wrong it is normally quite an effort to figure things out. This is why carton is being developed, as this creates a cache of all the distribution tarballs that you need to install frozen at specific versions so that you can predictably deploy your code. All of that said though; if you are happy to accept that risk and fix things when they break then locally installing should be fine for you. However, at the very minimum I would *strongly suggest* installing to a local::lib so that you can back up the old local lib before installing updates so you have a rollback point if things get messed up.

1. [Carton](https://metacpan.org/module/Carton)
2. [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib)
3. [perlbrew](https://metacpan.org/module/perlbrew)

Comment: I think maybe we're referring to two different things. I am talking about pulling a specific branch or 'version' of the application code from a central source control system, like GitHub for example. It seems that you are referring to the dependencies themselves, i.e. CPAN packages. I agree that very good care needs to be taken to ensure that your CPAN module versions are consistent across nodes, including your development/staging environments, however pulling a specific branch of source to each node during deployment seems like the way to ensure consistency of the application software itself.

Comment: One more question. In your experience with using Carton, how good has it been at handling the dependencies of dependencies? Meaning, if my Makefile.PL only contains the packages my application explicitly 'require' or 'use' how good is Carton at sorting out the dependencies of those modules?

Comment: Carton just uses the CPAN tools underneath, so all the dependencies of your dependencies will be installed so long as your dependencies properly declare all of their dependencies. It isn't impossible for a CPAN dep to be missing dependencies, but if you find that just let the package maintainer know and they'll fix it for you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you need to deploy from source like that. There is no real difference between installing from a git tag for a version and installing from a premade package made from that tag. Carton doesn't prevent you from installing from source, though, as you can just store the carton cache in the tag alongside your code and install it and your code when you need to install from your SCM. Just keep in mind that there are a LOT of tarballs in that cache, so it is pretty brutal on your SCM to keep committing new versions of the cache with your code.

Comment: A heads up: the reason why we prefer to package the mega libraries ( a local lib of internal and CPAN code at fixed versions ) as an RPM is that we can harness the system package manager to ensure that binaries dependencies are installed properly ( and at the right versions ) when install our application. If you install from source via SCM you will need to be very careful to manage those binary dependencies in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

If it has some significant CPAN dependencies, then you might want to either write a small script that uses `CPAN::Shell` to install the necessary modules or edit the `Makefile.PL` of your application so that it reflects the necessary dependencies in the `BUILD_REQUIRES` portion of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [sparrowdo](https://sparrowhub.org/) a perl6 configuration management tool, it comes with some handy plugins related to perl5 deployment, like installing cpan packages or deploying psgi application.

Update: this link https://dev.to/melezhik/deploying-perl5-application-by-sparrowdo-9mb could be useful.

Disclosure - I am the tool author.